# Magento 2.2.5: How to join a table with a repository

Tags: magento2, database, sql

I am trying to join table 'cataloginventory_stock_status' with order item table using OrderItemRepositoryInterface and searchCriteriaBuilder.

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                       ->addFilter('product_type', 'simple', 'eq')
                       ->create();
$collection = $this->orderItemRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

$collection->getSelect()->join(array('stock' => 'cataloginventory_stock_status'), 'main_table.product_id = stock.product_id', 'stock.stock_status')
               ->where('stock.stock_status = 1')
               ->columns('SUM(qty_ordered) as total_qty')
               ->group('main_table.product_id')
               ->order(array('total_qty DESC', 'name ASC'));
return $collection;
```

When i `echo $collection->getSelect();`

then its show write query, but got wrong data on template file.

Any solution for this please.

Answer (score 3):

Just use collection directly by injecting it in your constructor instead of repository because actual implementations of `getList` method are not powerful enough to permit additional joins.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
{
    $this->orderItemCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

...

$collection = $this->orderItemCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('product_type', 'simple');
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('stock' => 'cataloginventory_stock_status'), 'main_table.product_id = stock.product_id', 'stock.stock_status')
               ->where('stock.stock_status = 1')
               ->columns('SUM(qty_ordered) as total_qty')
               ->group('main_table.product_id')
               ->order(array('total_qty DESC', 'name ASC'));
return $collection;
```

Comment: This one working perfectly and saved a lot of time but I wonder how can we apply the same with repository as context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a beautiful post about joins in repositories...

https://fishchenko.com/blog/magento-2-join-table-in-orderrepositorygetlist-custom-field/

Credits: VLADIMIR FISHCHENKO - https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/61712/vladimir-fishchenko